# Calling Angular resource function on controller init only works on init

Tags: angularjs, controller, resources

I have an app that expects a URL like:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/patients?uuid=643fa655-b82a-4c02-b445-62d2c966867d
```

So if a uuid is present then load up the patient data, which is working with the following code:

```
var loadPatientChart = function(uuid){
    PatientsResource.getPatient({
        patientID:uuid
    }, 
    function(patient){
        $scope.patient = patient.data[0];
        console.log($scope.patient);
    });
};

if ("uuid" in $location.search()) {
    var obj = $location.search();
    loadPatientChart(obj.uuid);
}
```

The problem I am having is I need to call the loadPatientChart again later on the same controller using:

```
var unbind = $scope.$on('emmittedPatientUuid', function(event, uuid) {
    console.log('emmittedPatientUuid');
    loadPatientChart(uuid);
});
$scope.$on('$destroy', unbind);
```

This calls the function and I can verify that the data is returned and the $scope is updated using batarang but the view is not updating. No changes are visible. If I remove the call on init then the emit function works continuously as expected. I have also tried calling $apply at the end of the function with no joy. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to call it like this?

```
function(patient){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.patient = patient.data[0];
      console.log($scope.patient);
    })
});
```

Comment: Yeah I'm getting this error:

Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest

Comment: If the scope is updated then it's clearly a $digest problem `$scope.$apply` or `$scope.$digest` should fix it

Comment: Yeah that was my first hunch as well but I have tried both $scope.$apply and $scope.$digest like you answer as well as other variations but cant seem to crack it. The error link suggests wrapping in a timeout but that didn't work either.

Comment: It was a scope problem. Check my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a stupid mistake. I should have used $rootScope.$emit instead as the broadcast was on $rootScope

```
var unbind = $rootScope.$on('emmittedPatientUuid', function(event, uuid) {
    loadPatientChart(uuid);
});
$scope.$on('$destroy', unbind);
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't use $rootScope there, did you used a broadcast or emit? from event name `$rootScope.$on('emmittedPatientUuid', function(event, uuid) {` I would say it was emit and emits sends event up in tree while broadcast do it down the tree from parents to childs - hope that makes any sense